# Creating inside keys in a dictionary using a for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested, key

I am creating a dictionary from a table using a for loop. The goal is to use a for loop to create a dictionary with nested key-value pairs.

The table is in text format The first line is the header and looks like this:

```
AAA|BBB|CCC
zzz|100|xy
zzz|50|xy
xxx|200|xy
xxx|100|xy
zzz|300|xz
zzz|400|xz
xxx|200|xz
xxx|700|xz
```

To get an totals by AAA, (in AAA:CCC key value pair), the code was successful:

```py
dict = {}

with open('data.txt') as table:
    table.readline()
    for line in table:
        (AAA, BBB, CCC) = line.split("|")
        dict[AAA] = dict[AAA] + int(BBB) if AAA in dict else int(BBB)
```

The output was as expected:

```
{'zzz': 850, 'xxx': 1200}
```

The next step, (and where I am stuck) is how to perform an iteration to create an inside key, in the format

```
{'zzz':{xy:150, xz:700}, 'xxx':{xy:300, xz:900}}
```

This is what I have so far, but do not understand how to insert the insideKey into this dictionary:

```py
dict = {}
new_dict = {}

with open('data.txt') as table:
    table.readline()
    for line in table:
        (AAA, BBB, CCC) = line.split("|")
        dict[AAA] = dict[AAA] + (new_dict[CCC] + int(BBB)) if CCC in new_dict else int(BBB)
```

I understand that I can not add an insideKey by using + but was unable to find a method to do this.

Expected Output:

```
{'zzz':{xy:150, xz:700}, 'xxx':{xy:300, xz:900}}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with duplicate values: `xxx|200|xy
xxx|100|xy` what should `{xxx:{ xy:?}}` be?

Comment: Mark Meyer: it would appear that N N wants to sum them.

Comment: Mark, it should be added together, {xxx:{xy:300}}. Think of it as xxx is an apple, 200 is the quantity, xy is Kevin, the person that bought that quantity. In the next instance, xxx - apples, 100 quantity, also bought by Kevin (xy). xz would be another person, say Mike. Therefore, our dictionary keys and values would be `{apple:{Kevin:300, Mike:900}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to set the initial values. As you loop through just set the appropriate default or use `get` to get the inner values or zero:

```
d = {}
with open('data.txt') as table:
    next(table)
    for line in table:
        (AAA, BBB, CCC) = map(str.strip, line.split("|"))
        outer = d.setdefault(AAA, {})
        outer[CCC] = outer.get(CCC, 0) + int(BBB)
```

**result:**

```
{'zzz': {'xy': 150, 'xz': 700}, 'xxx': {'xy': 300, 'xz': 900}}
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick recommendation: don't use 'dict' as a name for a dictionary *instance*, since it's also the name for the dictionary *class*.  Python lets you modify the bindings to built-in names.  This is powerful, but if you ever needed to use the dict() constructor after that, you wouldn't be able to do it.

Now, on to your question.  I think that you're trying to accomplish too much in too few lines of code.  There's no shame in writing multiple, explicit lines in place of that dictionary assignment.  I'm also going to suggest that you reorganize the problem by building an easier dictionary as an intermediate step.

Dictionary keys can be any immutable data type that can be hashed.  That includes tuples which contain only immutable data.  This program gives you the data summed the way you want, but not quite organized exactly the way you want:

```
dct = {}
with open('data.txt') as table:
    table.readline()
    for line in table:
        (AAA, BBB, CCC) = line.split("|")
        v = int(BBB)     # value
        k = (AAA, CCC)   # key
        try:
            dct[k] += v  # existing key
        except KeyError:
            dct[k] = v   # new key
```

At this point, *dct* contains:

```
{('zzz', 'xy'): 150, ('xxx', 'xy'): 300, ('zzz', 'xz'): 700, ('xxx', 'xz'): 900}
```

Now, use a second loop to create a new dictionary, reorganized the way that you want.

```
result = {}
for (k1, k2), v in dct.items():
    try:
        result[k1][k2] = v
    except KeyError:
        result[k1] = {k2 : v}
```

Here's what's in *result*:

```
{'zzz': {'xy': 150, 'xz': 700}, 'xxx': {'xy': 300, 'xz': 900}}
```

I used three tricks that a beginning Python programmer may not know: more complex dictionary keys than just a string or number; exception handling; and tuple unpacking.  If you haven't learned these concepts yet, you will probably find them very useful.

Note: if you can use third-party packages, Pandas DataFrames are a great tool for getting this kind of work done.  Pandas is probably only worth the effort if you have a lot of data processing to do though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate using defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

with open('f0714.txt', 'r') as table:
    next(table)
    for line in table:
        (AAA, BBB, CCC) = map(str.strip, line.split("|"))

        if CCC not in d[AAA]:
            d[AAA][CCC] = int(BBB)
        else:
            d[AAA][CCC] += int(BBB)

print(dict(d))

'''
{'zzz': {'xy': 150, 'xz': 700}, 'xxx': {'xy': 300, 'xz': 900}}
'''
```

Comment: At this point go all-in: `d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))` to skip the `if` entirely, then `print({k: dict(v) for k, v in dict(d).items()})` to remove the inner defaultdicts.